# In PL/SQL how to initialiaze the value of Table type with Synonym name

Tags: oracle, plsql, compiler-errors, variable-assignment

I want to initialiaze the value of `MY_PERSON_TABLE` table's columns in `FN_INITIALIZE` function.

Below is the code. This question could be considered as an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070718/how-to-initialize-type-of-record-and-overcome-ora-06530-reference-to-uninitiali/49072884?noredirect=1#comment85174471_49072884)

Issue I am facing is, I am not able to compile the code and assign some value to the FNAME, ID.

```
create table MY_PERSON_TABLE
(
ID NUMBER(20),
FNAME VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE SYNONYM SYNONYM_PERSONAL FOR MY_PERSON_TABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST IS

TYPE TY_PERSONAL IS TABLE OF SYNONYM_PERSONAL%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

TYPE TY_PERSON IS RECORD(
PERSONAL TY_PERSONAL
);

END TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_BODY IS

FUNCTION FN_INITIALIZE(P_ACTION IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
L_TO_INITIALIZE TY_PERSON;

BEGIN
L_TO_INITIALIZE.PERSONAL := NEW SYNONYM_PERSONAL();
--The above code throws "PLS-00222: no function with name .. exists in the scope"
--How to initialiaze the value of FNAME & ID of MY_PERSON_TABLE?

END FN_INITIALIZE;

END TEST_BODY;
BEGIN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several errors:

- `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_BODY` should be `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST` (and `END TEST_BODY` should also be `END TEST`).
- You do not need to initialise a record; they are automatically created with the fields initialised to `NULL`. It is objects that you need to initialise.
- `L_TO_INITIALIZE.PERSONAL := NEW SYNONYM_PERSONAL();` does not make sense as `SYNONYM_PERSONAL` is a synonym to a table and not to a record. Instead you just want to pick any index value (`23` for example) and just set the field values for the record without any need to initialise it.

Like this:

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56977/1)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST IS

  FUNCTION FN_INITIALIZE(P_ACTION IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
    L_TO_INITIALIZE TY_PERSON;
  BEGIN
    L_TO_INITIALIZE.PERSONAL(23).FNAME := 'A';
    L_TO_INITIALIZE.PERSONAL(23).ID    := 1;
    RETURN TRUE;
  END FN_INITIALIZE;
END TEST;
/
```

However, you should ask yourself:

- Why are you using a PL/SQL associative array? If you are going to use consecutive indexes then you should probably be using a collection.
- What are you going to do with the array? You are not returning it from the function.